# fork and pipe confusion from quiz

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

This is a quiz from my class, and it invovles concept around fork and pipe. I just have a several confusions about this code.

1) What does if((pid = fork() == 0) means? is it just checking fork using pid(process id), why does loop start with this?

2)close (p[1]); what does this part mean? closing the first integer of array P?

3)The while loop start after close, does it mean it read into p[0]'s size if it is not zero?

4.The two write lines, what does that mean, and why are they both named 1? are they happening at the same time?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int p[2];

int i, pid, status;
char buffer[20];
pipe(p);
if((pid = fork() == 0) {

close (p[1]);
while (( i = read (p[0], buffer, sizeof("abcdefghi"))) != 0)
{ buffer [i] = '\0';
printf("read %d bytes: %s\n", i, buffer);

}
close(p[0]);
exit (0);
}

write(p[1], "abcdefghi', sizeof("abcdefghi"));

write(p[1], "123456789', sizeof("123456789"));

close(p[0]);
close(p[1]);
while(wait(&status)!= pid);
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Those are all good questions. You'll find the answers in the Linux man pages for `fork` and `pipe`. You'll learn a whole lot more if you try to understand it first from the man pages. And it's good to become familiar with man pages as you'll find you need to constantly refer to them (even very experienced programmers need to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should RTFM but :-

1. fork() creates an identical copy of the current procedure running from the same line of code. The only difference between the two copies is the return code from fork(). This will be 0 if you are in the newly created copy or the process id of the newly created copy if you are in the original executable (or -1 if something went wrong).
2. pipe(p) creates a pipe and returns two file handles in the array "p". the first handle is the output from the pipe opened for reading, the second handle is the input to the pipe open for writing. So close(p[1]) closes the input to the pipe ( this is in the new process which reads from the pipe, it is considered good practice to close the file descriptor you are not using!)
3. The while loop is checking "i" the return code from the read from the pipe file, this will return 0 when there is nothing to read.